# how to sort the date in sub-list using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, sublist

```
trading_info = [['1','1000',"symbol_name1",'1000','1100','950','1050','10000','2021-06-08'],
                ['2','2000',"symbol_name2",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-06-07'],
                ['3','3000',"symbol_name3",'1500','1200','850','1050','20000','2021-06-09'],
                ['4','4000',"symbol_name4",'10007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-01-05'],
                ['5','5000',"symbol_name5",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2022-07-07'],
                ['6','6000',"symbol_name6",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-06-08'],
                ['7','7000',"symbol_name7",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-08-02'],
                ['8','8000',"symbol_name8",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-01-01'],
                ['9','9000',"symbol_name9",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-10-10'],
                ['10','10000',"symbol_name10",'1007','1200','850','1050','2000','2021-06-14']]
for i in range(0,len(trading_info)):
    for j in range(0,len(trading_info)-i-1):
        if(trading_info[j][8]>trading_info[j+1][8]):
            trade=trading_info[j]
            trading_info[j]=trading_info[j+1]
            trading_info[j+1]=trade

trading_info = trading_info
df = pd.DataFrame(trading_info_sorted[0:],columns=trading_info_sorted[0])
df.columns=["index","symbol_token","symbol_name","opening","high","low","closing","volume","date"]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame(trading_info)
frame.sort_values(8) # column 8
```